# Translation different from culture and ui culture in asp mvc 3 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, translation, currentculture, currentuiculture

In my ASP MVC 3 site I added a folder **Resources** with 2 Resx files **Strings.resx** and **Strings.fr-FR.resx**, Acces modifier public, and provided translation.

I added in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="Auto" uiCulture="Auto"/>
```

and

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="culture" value="fr-FR" />
    <add key="uiculture" value="fr-FR" />
```

I also forced **french** language in CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture in **Application_AuthenticateRequest** and **Application_BeginRequest** in global.asax.

The problem is when displaying site in localhost, the language is translated in french.

When deploying the site on the server (after building the msi in a WebSetup project) The strings are not translated in french language although both culture and ui culture are "fr-FR" (displayed them in input hidden).

What can be the problem? Maybe something is missing in the config server? I can't find any issue about that in the internet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this approach is great http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the production server has different language sets
and with that

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

is set automatically... but this is just a guess since I do not know enough about your implementation...

but...

Here is a good, detailed article on that topic...

Globalization, Internationalization and Localization in ASP.NET MVC 3, JavaScript and jQuery - Part 1

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have published the folder containing the translation to fr-FR, in my case I did the translation in en-US and in the bin folder there is a sub-folder called en-US that contains the dll of the resource with the translation.